# Is composition of normal(regular) coverings, a normal(regular) covering?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

Let $r:X\to Y$, $q:Y\to Z$ normal(regular) coverings.

Is $p=q\circ r$ a normal covering?

My intuitional answer would be no.

First: A covering space $r:X\to Y$ is a normal covering if and only if every loop in $r_\star\left(\pi_1(X)\right)$ is normal subgroup of $\pi_1(Y)$.

My intuition is since problem reduces to $N\unlhd H\unlhd G$ then it is not necessary that $N\unlhd G$.

Can you help me to find any counterexample if my intuition is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Note, however, that there are two definitions of a *normal covering*:

A covering $p:Y \to X$ with path connected $Y$ is *normal* if

1. the group of deck transformations acts transitively on the fibers $p^{−1}(x)$.
2. $p_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0))$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$, where $y_0 \in p^{−1}(x_0)$.  Recall that $p_* : \pi_1(Y,y_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0)$ is injective.

For a path connected and locally path-connected space $X$ both concepts agree.

It is well-known that for a path-connected, locally path-connected and semilocally simply-connected $X$ (such spaces have a universal covering) each subgroup $H \subset \pi_1(X,x_0)$ admits a covering $p:Y \to X$ with path connected $Y$  such that $p_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0)) = H$.

Now let $X$ be a CW-complex whose fundamental group is the dihedral group $D_8$ of order $8$ which has the presentation $\langle x, a \mid a^4 = x^2 = xax^{-1}a = e \rangle $. Recall that each group occurs as the fundamental group of a suitable CW-complex. Since CW-complexes path-connected, locally path-connected and semilocally simply-connected, we find a covering $p:Y \to X$ with path connected $Y$  such that $p_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0)) = K = \lbrace e, x, a^2, a^2x \rbrace$ which is one of the Klein groups of order $4$ sitting in $D_8$. This is a normal subgroup of $D_8$. Next we find a covering $q:Z \to Y$ with path connected $Z$  such that $q_*(\pi_1(Z,z_0)) = C = \lbrace e, x \rbrace$ which is a normal subgroup of $K$. Then $p \circ q : Z \to X$ is a covering such that $(p \circ q)_*(\pi_1(Z,z_0)) = C \subset D_8$ which is a non-normal subgroup of $D_8$.